# Detect scroll on document but not inside a specific container

Tags: jquery

Not know whether a similar question exists, but the issue is to detect whether the user is scrolling a document or a container which is set to `overflow-y: auto`

The situation is explained in the attached image.

[image: Browser image]

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
 //IF NOT INSIDE #SOME_CONTAINER DO SOME ACTION
});
```

Comment: you can catch the scroll event on that specific container and cancel bubbling (`e.stopPropagation()`)

Comment: This should already be the default action. See the fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/nrivers/qqrjLbzr/